# how to remove widgets from the panel

Tags: panel

I can't seem to figure out how to remove a widget from my panel.
I added a link for Libre Math to my panel by mistake and want to remove it.
It's seems very easy to add a quick link to the panel but quite another to remove it.
Any ideas/solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 0):

If by panel you mean the Dock then right click with your mouse on the icon in the Dock you wish to remove and select `Remove from Favourites`.

Please be aware that this only removes the icon from the Dock, it does not remove the application from your system.

Another way of doing it is to click on the 9 dot `Show Applications` menu at the bottom of the Dock and navigate to the app concerned (LibreMath in your case) and again, right click and select `Remove from Favourites`.